# SSL enabled in sharepoint, reporting services broke

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, ssrs-2008

Everything was working fine and then SSL was enabled on a sharepoint 2010 site, and then reporting services broke.

The error now is when clicking on a report I get

The Web application at https://somesitecom/lte/Report Library/TestReport.rdl could not be found. Verify that you have typed the URL correctly. If the URL should be serving existing content, the system administrator may need to add a new request URL mapping to the intended application.

In SSRS 2008 R2, since we no longer have /ReportServer showing out reports, but instead actual site names:
http://somesite.com
http://somesite.com/my

I'm curious if the folders listed in SSRS need to be changed to https://somesite.com instead of http but Im not sure how. Maybe reinstalling is the way to go - but I would like to see if renaming these value s(or some other fix) works.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!